# tFPDF - Hindi text spelling is incorrect in pdf

Tags: php, fpdf

I want to write a hindi text in my pdf.

- At first, I downloaded the `ttf` font file from [google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/)
- After that I included the `ttf` file inside `font < unifont`
- After that, I added the fonts into my code:

  ```
  <?php
    require('tfpdf.php');

    $pdf = new tFPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->AddFont('NotoSerifDevanagari-Regular','','NotoSerifDevanagari-Regular.ttf',true);
    $pdf->SetFont('NotoSerifDevanagari-Regular','',10);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,'पूसीरे के रेसुब ने नाबालिगों समेत 12 लोगों को बचाया');
    $pdf->Output();
  ?>
  ```

The resultant text in the pdf shows like this:
[screenshot of my pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpPWK.png)

Here, as you can see the word **नाबालिगों** is incorrectly spelled. Why? How do I fix this?

Comment: tFPDF does not support complex scripts like Hindi.

Comment: Then what is the solution? What library should I use to write texts in Hindi, Bengali and other Indian languages?

Comment: You can use [mPDF](https://mpdf.github.io/) (however it's under GPL).

Answer (score 0):

see here :

[tFPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php)

This class is a modified version of FPDF that adds UTF-8 support

or this :

[UFPDF](https://acko.net/blog/ufpdf-unicode-utf-8-extension-for-fpdf/)

that adds UTF-8 support

but you could move to [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/)

Comment: Although the font is working, but the spelling of the text is incorrect

Comment: Please check my updated post for details

Comment: you could move to TCPDF which is much better at handling utf8 than FPDF check updated post

Comment: [TCPDF does not support Hindi](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/issues/199).